# jQuery and Intraweb?

Tags: jquery, dojo, intraweb

Anyone have a sample of doing a jQuery notification/popup/calendar in Intraweb ?

A simple example would be great..

Even better... dojo version would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Intraweb newsgroups I've posted a very basic example for using jQuery in Intraweb.

See atozedsoftware.intraweb.attachments (on nntp://news.atozed.com). Thread "JQuery sample project for André Aigneren", date November 23rd, 2009. Written in D2010 and IW 10. It is using the datepicker control.

The example is based on this blog: http://www.hadihariri.com/Blogs/Delphi/20080117.aspx.

Gert

Comment: Thanks.. After reading Hadi Hariri blog and some c# examples I got the code working.

Thanks. (Also thanks to everyone for their feedback).

Answer (score 2):

Visit [CGDevTools](http://www.cgdevtools.com) they have a jQuery components suite to use with Intraweb maybe they have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a popup message

http://jsbin.com/otinu3/edit

In case you have difficulty using jsbin (great sandbox for testing these things), the markup is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>Popup example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="popupMessage">This is the popup message</div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

and the JavaScript is as simple as

```
$('#popupMessage').dialog({title:'Here we go'});​
```

Comment: Whats the recommended way of calling/using these from Delphi Intraweb ? Is it via IWJQuery ? Constructor ? Any samples of integrating with Intraweb would be great...

Answer (score 1):

Dojo has the toaster widget for notifications:

demo : http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/widget/Toaster

api : http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.2/dojox.widget.Toaster

Works like a charm and is very configurable.

For popups use dojo's dialog widget.

For calendar use dojo's datepicker widget.

If you like you can have a notification with a link to lauch a popup that contains a calendar...

Comment: Whats the recommended way of calling/using these from Delphi Intraweb ? Is it via IWJQuery ? Constructor ? Any samples of integrating with Intraweb would be great...

Comment: the latter two widgets are dijit.Dialog and dijit.Calendar.  You'll find documentation and examples for both at the docs.dojocampus.org site.

Comment: Thanks.. But I'm after an example of calling/using the jQuery stuff from Intraweb.